# JavaFx Help of animation

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I have been doing some coding with JavaFx. I am still pretty new to JavaFx and just can't figure out how to do this. I am trying to build a game where the player has to dodge enemies. I was trying to make an animation where the enemies are coming down from the top of the screen to the bottom and a new enemy spawns after one of the other enemies go to a certain part of the screen. I want to make it that these enemies can change their speed after a certain time. For a summary, I want to do an animation that suits these features:

- Able to go from one point to the other
- speed is changeable
- Able to check the position in the middle of the movement

I have tried TranslateTransition and an AnimationTimer but they don't get to a high enough speed or I can't find the position in the middle of the movement.

Actually, Can I also get an explanation on how interpolate works on translateTransition.

Comment: This question is rather too broad for this forum. Have a look at [this blog](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html) (you need to read [this one](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html) first for general background), and also at a [simple example I wrote](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842).

Comment: Also please post any cod that you've tried.